# php getting values of form query string

Tags: php, forms

i am trying to post a form to php that contains multiple identical fields e.g. there can be multiple `body_styles` and multiple `make` and `model`

when i serialize the form i get the following output

```
SelectbsmContainer0=&body_style=hatchback&body_style=mpv&make=bmw&model=5+series+gran+turismo&valueA=200&valueB=800
```

how can i parse this at php end??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a certain PHP feature, you are going to have a lot of trouble unless you rename the fields so the names end with `[]`, at which point they will appear in `$_POST` as arrays.

Answer (score 5):

Change your html so that your fields are [an HTML "array"](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) like this:

```
<input name="body_style[]" value="" />
<input name="body_style[]" value="" />
```

Then you can access them via [PHP's `$_GET` super global](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) like so:

```
$first_body_style = $_GET['body_style'][0];
$second_body_style = $_GET['body_style'][1];
```

Or

```
foreach($_GET['body_styles'] as $value) {
    var_dump($value);
}
```

Comment: tnx for the answer with example... but David Dorward answered first so i have to accept his answer... +1

Comment: @john Umm... No he didn't. 2011-05-20 11:21:53Z versus 2011-05-20 11:23:19Z